# MongoDb ConnectionURL in jdoconfig.xml

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, jdo, datanucleus, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have setup a MongoDB instance on AWS and am trying to connect to it from another AWS instance where my web app is installed.

The following is the contents of my jdoconfig.xml file:

```
<jdoconfig xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jdo/jdoconfig_3_0.xsd">

    <persistence-manager-factory name="MY-PMF">
        <property name="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass"
            value="org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb://ec2-[...].eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/mydb" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.Mapping" value="mongodb" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName" value="myuser" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword" value="mypassword" />
        <property name="javax.jdo.option.Optimistic" value="false" />
        <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true" />
    </persistence-manager-factory>
</jdoconfig>
```

However, the web app cannot connect to the MongoDB instance.  The following are error messages from the logs:

```
com.mongodb.MongoException$Network: can't call something : localhost/127.0.0.1:27017//ec2-[...].eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/mydb
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:226)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:313)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:174)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:158)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:198)
    at com.mongodb.DB.command(DB.java:144)
    at com.mongodb.DB._doauth(DB.java:555)
    at com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(DB.java:492)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:200)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.MongoDBStoreManager.addClasses(MongoDBStoreManager.java:127)
    at org.datanucleus.store.AbstractStoreManager.addClass(AbstractStoreManager.java:1137)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.newObjectId(ObjectManagerImpl.java:3310)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.newObjectIdInstance(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1627)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.getObjectById(JDOPersistenceManager.java:1749)
    at com.myapp.server.auth.MyActionHandler.execute(MyActionHandler.java:67)
    at com.myapp.server.auth.MyActionHandler.execute(MyActionHandler.java:1)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.doExecute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:153)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchImpl.java:111)
    at com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.execute(AbstractDispatchServiceImpl.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:263)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:178)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:62)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterDefinition.doFilter(FilterDefinition.java:168)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:58)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:118)
    at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:27017] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.mongodb.DBPort._open(DBPort.java:222)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:111)
    at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:78)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:217)
    ... 55 more
```

It looks like the ConnectionURL is not correct; DataNucleus JDO implementation is trying to connect to localhost instead of the instance where my DB is located.

**Can anyone show me what the correct ConnectionURL should look like or if you think the problem is elsewhere point me to it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you haven't specified the connectionURL correctly, as per 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/mongodb/support.html

I'd expect something more like "mongodb:servername:/mydb" ... as per the doc

Comment: Changing the JDO config to: `<property name="javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:ec2-[...].eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/mydb" />` solved my problem. Note that the link that you supplied does not have the second colon, which seems to be required with `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL`.  Additionally, I get a `NumberFormatException` if the port is left blank.

Comment: @Chania how did you solve the `NumberFormatException` error? :) When i set the value to `mongodb:ec2-[...].eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/mydb`, i would get `NumberFormatException`. When i set the value with port number such as `mongodb:ec2-[...].eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:27017/mydb`, i will get other errors...

Comment: There are zero known problems with putting host:port in datanucleus-mongodb. If you are having problems then perhaps you're using some ancient version, or you have put it in incorrectly. Either way, putting something in the comments of some old issue isn't really the way to address it